# Proper way to convert xml to dictionary

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm not sure if this is the best way to convert this xml result into a dictionary, Besides doing that, is there any proper way to convert to dict ?

xml from http request result:

```
<Values version="2.0">
  <value name="configuration">test</value>
  <array name="configurationList" type="value" depth="1">
    <value>test</value>
  </array>
  <value name="comment">Upload this for our robot.</value>
  <array name="propertiesTable" type="record" depth="1">
    <record javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
      <value name="name">date_to_go</value>
      <value name="value">1990</value>
    </record>
    <record javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
      <value name="name">role</value>
      <value name="value">Survivor</value>
    </record>
    <record javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
      <value name="name">status</value>
      <value name="value">living</value>
    </record>
    <record javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
      <value name="name">user</value>
      <value name="value">John&amp;nbsp;Connor</value>
    </record>
  </array>
  <null name="propertiesList"/>
</Values>
```

Code to convert the xml to dictionary ( which is working properly )

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml)
mom = []
mim = []
configuration = tree.find('value[@name="configuration"]').text
comment = tree.find('value[@name="comment"]').text
prop = (configuration, comment)
mom.append(prop)

for records in tree.findall('./array/record'):
    me = []
    for child in records.iter('value'):
        me.append(child.text)
    mim.append(me)

for key, value in mim:
    mi_dict = dict()
    mi_dict[key] = value
    mom.append(mi_dict)

print(mom)
```

The result ( working as intended ):

```
[('test', 'Upload this for our robot.'), {'date_to_go': '1990'}, {'role': 'Survivor'}, {'status': 'living'}, {'user': 'John&nbsp;Connor'}]
```

EDIT:

Sorry if i wans't clear, but the code described is working as expected. but i'm not sure if this is the proper way ( python way, pythonic or clean ) to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the result mentioned on the question is what i have. Sorry if i wans't clear, but the intention is to discover if there a proper way to do it ( the parsing )

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its too bad. You can make some minor changes to be a bit more pythonic

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml)
mom = []
mim = []
configuration = tree.find('value[@name="configuration"]').text
comment = tree.find('value[@name="comment"]').text
prop = (configuration, comment)
mom.append(prop)

for records in tree.findall('./array/record'):
    mim.append([child.text for child in records.iter('value')])

mom += [{k:v} for k, v in mim.iteritems()]

print(mom)
```